# Solana address, Spl token, Mint

Tags: spl-token

can anyone help me to make a new solana address and new spl token and show me how to mint those into the solana address through CLI

Answer (score 2):

This is well documented in the solana docs. Im assuming youve gotten the cli installed and working.

Regardless making a token instructions have been around since sola launched 2 years ago. Instead of rewriting existing work check out the below tutorial:
https://moralis.io/how-to-create-a-solana-token-in-5-steps/

If still running into issues pls share the command and screnshot the output

Answer (score 1):

`solana-keygen new` for a new keypair to sign with

`spl-token --help`  for a new token and transferring of the token

Answer (score 1):

The solana documentation provides easy-to-follow steps to fulfill your requirements using the solana-cli.

1. Creating a new solana account: [[details]](https://spl.solana.com/token#setup).
2. Creating and minting your own token: [[details]](https://spl.solana.com/token#example-creating-your-own-fungible-token).

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool which can help you to directly create spl/ spl22 token with custom token address also.  You can Manage and update token information also

[SPL](https://app.hypersol.xyz/solana-token-manager/create-spl-token)
[spl22](https://app.hypersol.xyz/solana-token-manager/create-spl-token-2022)
[Manage](https://app.hypersol.xyz/solana-token-manager/manage-token)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/7880)

Comment: updated links, pls check now